# Jenkins iOS Build - Inject Jenkins build number into app's main plist file

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

So I have a Jenkins job running which builds my iOS application. I want to take the auto-incremented Jenkins build number, and inject it into the application's main plist file (so that I can read it in-code, to display on the UI).

Does this need to be a script specified in the Jenkins job, or in an Xcode build-phase?

What process should I be following?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `agvtool` to auto increment the build number. This command line tool is part of the Xcode tools, so you should already have it installed.

There are a few preparations you need to do in your project to make agvtool work:

1. Open your project in Xcode and click on the project
2. Select the target you want to set the build version for
3. Go to Build Settings and make sure you have "All" selected
4. Scroll down to Versioning and select Apple Generic as the versioning system
5. Set the current project version to 1, also set your build number in the project overview (general tab) to the same build number

Now you should be able to open a command line in your project folder and type

```
agvtool what-version
```

This will output the current version of your project (1). Next go to your Jenkins and add a Shell Script build step. This should happen before the project is built!

In this build step you can increment the build number:

```
agvtool next-version -all
```

or set a specific version:

```
agvtool new-version -all 10
```

Above will set the version to 10. You can also use Jenkins environment variables here instead of 10, like `${BUILD_NUMBER}` for example.

The `-all` switch is used to also update the `CFBundleVersion` of your project.